# "Invalid Argument" error in RStudio Server

Tags: r

I'm having an issue with RStudio Server. I can't open files and every click I do produces an "Invalid Argument" statement. I've previously dealt with another issue "Cannot establish connection to R session" by deleting suspended sessions folder. It fixed the connection error.

Now I have this new "Invalid Argument" and had to force RStudio session to end several times. I'm not a programming expert or administrator.
Any ideas would be great and most helpful.

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)

Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:`

 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8  
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:

[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

[1] tools_3.1.2
```

Error Messages:

> 21 Apr 2015 09:31:40 [rsession-xnim003] ERROR system error 22 (Invalid argument); OCCURRED AT: core::Error session::source_database::get(const std::string&, boost::shared_ptr) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionSourceDatabase.cpp:479; LOGGED FROM: core::Error session::source_database::list(std::vector, std::allocator > >*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionSourceDatabase.cpp:599

Comment: You probably will get more help directly asking to [RStudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us)

Comment: @Assu: I've encountered the same error. Did you find out the cause of this error and/or how to resolve it?